# Is it possible check if a variable respect two conditions on different rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Well, I have a data frame with product sales. One of the variables is the 'Product Identification' and another is the 'Item_Weight'. The 'Item_Weight' have some missing values. So, I want to know if there is any product that have in a row the 'Item_Weight' filled and in other row don't.

The data frame is like this:

```
 Item_Identifier  Item_Weight Item_Fat_Content  Item_Visibility    Item_Type  \
0           FDA15         9.30          Low Fat         0.016047        Dairy   
1           DRC01         5.92          Regular         0.019278  Soft Drinks   
2           FDN15        17.50          Low Fat         0.016760         Meat   

   Item_MRP Outlet_Identifier  Outlet_Establishment_Year Outlet_Size  \
0  249.8092            OUT049                       1999      Medium   
1   48.2692            OUT018                       2009      Medium   
2  141.6180            OUT049                       1999      Medium   

  Outlet_Location_Type        Outlet_Type  Item_Outlet_Sales  
0               Tier 1  Supermarket Type1          3735.1380  
1               Tier 3  Supermarket Type2           443.4228  
2               Tier 1  Supermarket Type1          2097.2700
```

---

So, what I have done so far was creating a new df just with the 'Item_Identifier' and the 'Item_Weight' and fill the missing values with (-1) and all other values with (-2) on the 'Item_Weight':

```
dfAux = df[['Item_Identifier','Item_Weight']]

dfAux['Item_Weight'].fillna(-1, inplace=True)

dfAux.loc[dfAux['Item_Weight'] > 0, 'Item_Weight'] = -2
```

After this I tried a lot of things to see if I can find the 'Item_Identifier''s that have the value (-1) and (-2). None of these attempts was successful, so i need your help.

Just you to know I am new to data science and python, but I have tried to find the solution on stackoverflow, during several days. Obviously I lack some technical terms so I have some difficulty in find similar questions to mine. I am sorry for bothering.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rows with 'Item_Weight' value as -1 or -2 then here is the code you can use to get this task done.

```
dfAux[(dfAux['Item_Weight']==-1) | (dfAux['Item_Weight']==-2) ]
```

The above code will return all the rows which has "Item_Weight" value as -1 or -2.

The 'or' and 'and' python statements require truth-values. For pandas these are considered ambiguous so you should use bitwise operators :

**|** for performing **or** operation

and

**&** for performing **and** operation.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just don't understand, looking at the code, while using the (and) operator, if the code is using the key of the product 'item_identifier'. In order to, check on the dataset if some product have the weight in some rows and on others don't.

Comment: @LuísLimaMoreira Is it a question? I didn't get what you are trying to tell.

Comment: What I want is tell the computer the following: Look at the Item_Identifier column and find all the rows with the same keys. Then look at the column Item_Weight and check if among those rows we have values of -1 AND -2. (Ex: On Row 12 and 33 on one we have -1 and on other we have -2). Because this tell me that I have missing weights that I have those weights, on other rows that respect to the same product.              My question is; your code is doing this? Because I don't see nothing on it that uses the 'Item_Identifier' column.  I am sorry, I am new to this so I am lacking the bases. Thank

Comment: Above code will return all the rows and columns of dataframe in which rows have 'item_weight' as -1 or -2.

If you want to get a part of dataframe, you can append column name at the end of above code as:

dfAux[(dfAux['Item_Weight']==-1) | (dfAux['Item_Weight']==-2) ]['item_identifier']

This will return all the row in 'item_identifier' which has item_weight' value as -1 or -2.
Is this the answer of your question?
Or you are seeking something else?
let me know what exactly do you want to get from the data, so that I can help you on that @LuísLimaMoreira.
Thanks